# Angular.js, updating view after invoking methods from outside of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qt

I'm creting Qt/Webkit hybrid application, and I wanted to use angular for view framework. I have problem with refreshing angular views after invoking QT slot. Here's my JS code:

```
(function(){

var AkriviaStoreApp = angular.module('AkriviaStoreApp', []);


AkriviaStoreApp.controller('StatesController', function () {

    var this_SC = this;

    function updateStates(passed_object) {
        this_SC.states= passed_object.states;
        this_SC.test = 'oczko';
        this_SC.$apply();
    }

    QtStatesJsController.requestFinished.connect(this, updateStates);

    this.states =  [{Book : {name : "Ladne"}, State: {price: "21:09"}}];
    this.test = "nosek";

});

})();
```

The view on HTML stays as initialized. Qt is invoking *updateStates()* correcty, i checked with console.log and data appears to be ok. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the controller itself does not have an `$apply()` method, the `$scope` does. So try injecting `$scope` invoke its `$apply()` method instead.

Something like this:

```
(function(){

    var AkriviaStoreApp = angular.module('AkriviaStoreApp', []);


    AkriviaStoreApp.controller('StatesController', function ($scope) {

        var this_SC = this;

        function updateStates(passed_object) {
            this_SC.states= passed_object.states;
            this_SC.test = 'oczko';
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        QtStatesJsController.requestFinished.connect(this, updateStates);

        this.states =  [{Book : {name : "Ladne"}, State: {price: "21:09"}}];
        this.test = "nosek";

    });

})();
```